# How change the device name in WiFi direct p2p?

Tags: android, wifi-direct, wifip2p, device-name

Is it possibile to change the device name of WiFi direct through the code? I've tried to:

```
private WifiP2pDevice wDevice;
wDevice.deviceName = "newName";
```

But, obviously it doesn't work.
Any idea?!

Comment: Is this question similar to the following? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27315198/android-rename-devices-name-for-wifi-direct

As in you want to change the device name of the one broadcasting?

Answer (score 10):

Following code use Reflection api of Java,It is less preferrable due to lack of efficiency but Android does not provide another way so, You can use it works with charm :

```
    try {
        Method m = wpm.getClass().getMethod(
                "setDeviceName",
                new Class[] { WifiP2pManager.Channel.class, String.class,
                        WifiP2pManager.ActionListener.class });

        m.invoke(WifiP2pManager wifimngr,WifiP2pManager.Channel wifichannel, new_name, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {
            public void onSuccess() {
                //Code for Success in changing name
            }

            public void onFailure(int reason) {
                //Code to be done while name change Fails
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: could you possibly elaborate and explain why this code would hep out, and what it does? Thanks

Comment: Could you please answer this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/53607516/9640177 - how to get current device name

Answer (score 9):

This code works for me.

```
WifiP2pManager manager;
WifiP2pManager.Channel channel;
    try {
       manager = (WifiP2pManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_P2P_SERVICE);
        channel = manager.initialize(this, getMainLooper(), new WifiP2pManager.ChannelListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChannelDisconnected() {
                manager = (WifiP2pManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_P2P_SERVICE);
            }
        });
        Class[] paramTypes = new Class[3];
        paramTypes[0] = WifiP2pManager.Channel.class;
        paramTypes[1] = String.class;
        paramTypes[2] = WifiP2pManager.ActionListener.class;
        Method setDeviceName = manager.getClass().getMethod(
                "setDeviceName", paramTypes);
        setDeviceName.setAccessible(true);

        Object arglist[] = new Object[3];
        arglist[0] = channel;
        arglist[1] = devName;
        arglist[2] = new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                Log.d("setDeviceName succeeded", "true");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int reason) {
                Log.d("setDeviceName failed", "true");
            }
        };
        setDeviceName.invoke(manager, arglist);

    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Tested it on Android 6.0.1 today - works great. Thank you.

Comment: it works, are there any risk for security? what about the intent broadcast with WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION?

Comment: Also tested on 6.0 today. works perfectly! big thanks.

Comment: Does this still work on latest android versions?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (action.equals(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION))
{
    WifiP2pDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_WIFI_P2P_DEVICE);
    // device.deviceName
}
```

this code works

Reference-
[How to get wifi direct devices name from WifiP2pDeviceList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30256505/how-to-get-wifi-direct-devices-name-from-wifip2pdevicelist)