# Android naming a P2P device

Tags: java, android, reflection, p2p, wifip2p

I was wondering if anybody could shed some light on an issue regarding WifiP2pDevice's name field.

As you may already know, WifiP2pDevice has a devicename field, but no methods to "set" the devicename, only to read it.

As discussed in this post:
[How change the device name in WiFi direct p2p?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24851961/how-change-the-device-name-in-wifi-direct-p2p)

It may be possible to set the device's name via reflection.  I know it is bad custom, but since the API doesn't support this and I need this functionality in my application, how would I go about doing this?

As of now, my code:

```
    try
    {
        method = myManager.getClass().getMethod("setDeviceName",  new Class[] { WifiP2pManager.Channel.class, String.class,
                WifiP2pManager.ActionListener.class });
        method.invoke(myManager, myChannel, getIntent().getStringExtra(NETWORK_NAME));
        Toast.makeText(this, "Name set successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Currently, the application gets to this point and returns a NoSuchMethodException, implying that the setDeviceName does not exist.  Any help/alternatives on java reflection?

EDIT 1: As per the suggestion, I have changed my code to use a WifiP2pManager instead of a WifiP2pDevice to do the getClass() call on, however, the program crashes at the method.invoke line claming that the setDeviceName method expects 3 arguements, but only received 2 (even though mode code as it stands now is sending 3).

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the variable naming from the [answer to the question you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26931608/1993204):

```
Method m = wpm.getClass().getMethod(
            "setDeviceName",
            new Class[] { WifiP2pManager.Channel.class, String.class,
                    WifiP2pManager.ActionListener.class });
```

you should probably call this method (`getClass().getMethod(...)`) on a WifiP2pManager object and not on the WifiP2pDevice object (I think `wpm` stands for **W**ifi**P**2p**M**anager).

Comment: I could not make this work either, I'm still tweaking the syntax to see if I make any progress with this insight, however.