# How to get wifi direct devices name from WifiP2pDeviceList

Tags: java, android, wifi-direct

I want to get the wi-fi direct name when I execute request peers, here is my code:

```
if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {

    Log.d(tag, "success discover the peers ");

    if (mManager != null) {
        mManager.requestPeers(mChannel, new WifiP2pManager.PeerListListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPeersAvailable(WifiP2pDeviceList peers) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if (peers != null) {
                    if (device.deviceName.equals("ABC")) {
                        Log.d(tag, "found device!!! ");

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "FOUND!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                }
            }
        });
    } else {
        Log.d(tag, "mMaganger == null");
    }
}
```

I want to get the deviceName from the list of peers so that I can found that one named "ABC". Any idea?

Comment: what do you mean by **wifi-direct** name? You mean the [deviceName](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/p2p/WifiP2pDevice.html#deviceName)!!? coz device name is very straight forward to obtain...

Comment: I edited my qs, I want to find the deviceName from list of peers. But I can't figure out what wrong of my code. I can't get the expected result..

Comment: Thanks for editing. I guessed so. Could you paste some more of your code to get exactly you are going wrong in getting the name ? I mean the part where you are trying to get the device name...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want others device name:

```
wifiP2pManager.requestPeers(wifiChannel, new WifiP2pManager.PeerListListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPeersAvailable(WifiP2pDeviceList wifiP2pDeviceList) {

            for (WifiP2pDevice device : wifiP2pDeviceList.getDeviceList())
            {
                if (device.deviceName.equals("ABC")) Log.d(tag, "found device!!! ");
                // device.deviceName
            }
        }
    });
```

If you want your device name get it in the receiver:

```
if (action.equals(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION))
{
    WifiP2pDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_WIFI_P2P_DEVICE);
    // device.deviceName
}
```

If you want to change device name:

```
try {
    Method method = wifiP2pManager.getClass().getMethod("setDeviceName",
        WifiP2pManager.Channel.class, String.class, WifiP2pManager.ActionListener.class);

    method.invoke(wifiP2pManager, wifiChannel, "New Device Name", new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {
        public void onSuccess() {}

        public void onFailure(int reason) {}
    });
} catch (Exception e)   {}
```

Comment: I think I had confused to get the own deviceName & other devices Name. Thanks for point it out.

Comment: @Ali very clearly explained. i just didn't want to give away code without him trying it, as it was easy to find :P :P cheers

Comment: @user2301281 you're welcome. Please mark the answer if your satisfied. Thank you

Comment: @user2301281 I really suggest looking at WiFi Direct demo in android SDK.

Comment: @Ali, yes. I already looking & try the WifiDirectDemo in sample before. But inside the broadcast sample don't have the "onPeersAvailable()"  part. So I can't get the idea. Sorry for my poor coding skills. & very thank you for clear the idea. =D

Comment: @user2301281 There is no need to perform to perform requestPeers or other WiFiP2P methods inside the receiver, you can just do it at the beginning of your activity or fragment.

Comment: @Ali, u mean without using requestPeers I can direct execute deviceName.equals("ABC")??

Comment: @user2301281 No, it's clear that you don't have the peers if you don't request them first. My point is you can request peers anywhere, not just inside the wifi receiver.

Comment: @Ali, noted. Thanks for pointed out so many concept of wifi direct. It's really help me. =D

Answer (score 2):

You have the object for `WifiP2pDeviceList`(peers)

Call the method `getDeviceList()` on peers which returns a collection(list) of P2p devices `Collection<WifiP2pDevice>`

Then iterate through the collection element which is a `WifiP2pDevice` and it would contain the `deviceName` property which is what you need exactly.

Refer [this](http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct.html) training from android developers

Hope you are able to get it

Comment: I can't really get the idea of "iterate through the collection element". Can you explain more detail? Sorry, i'm newbie. ><

Comment: @user2301281 Since it contains a 'list' of devices, you need to run through each elements in the list to get it's deviceName. Refer to the `for` loop in @Ali's reply

Comment: thanks. I think I more clear about it now. I will have a try. Thanks for your kindly suggestion. It really save my day. =DD