# Add Suffix to name of WiFi Direct Group name. (similar to what PDANet does)

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifi-direct, wifip2p, ssid

I am trying to create a **WiFi Direct Group with a custom name**. But after exploring all the options I came to know that we cannot change the name and Android OS decide itself about the name of **WiFi Direct Group**

I even tried **Reflection** to achieve the same but it didn't worked on **Android Nougat and above.**

I am using the following code to create the WiFi Direct Group:

```
WifiP2pManager manager = (WifiP2pManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_P2P_SERVICE);
WifiP2pManager.Channel channel = manager.initialize(this, getMainLooper(), null);
 manager.createGroup(channel, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Group Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(int i) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Group Creation Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
```

But when I tried PDANet+ app they were able to create a WiFi Direct Group Name with a suffix PDANet.

For example:

My app generates the following Group name : **DIRECT-mq-ONEPLUS**

While PDANet generates: **DIRECT-Dj-ONEPLUS A6000-PdaNet**

So I was wondering how they are adding the Suffix to the WiFi Direct Group name. If anyone can help me on this that will be much help.!

Thanks.!

Comment: Did you try this solution? https://stackoverflow.com/a/33127148/3024933

Comment: @just Already tried this but getting a **NoSuchMethodException** in my Android P device.

Comment: What is your compileSdkVersion number? I have this method on 28